# Añadir lista de urls en Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Actualmente me encuentro haciendo una aplicación donde tengo un RecyclerView de WebViews con video recibidos por urls de youtube.

```
 recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerYt);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<DataSetListYouTube>();

    DataSetListYouTube dataSetListYouTube = new DataSetListYouTube("https://www.youtube.com/embed/******");
    arrayList.add(dataSetListYouTube);

    YoutubeAdapter youtubeAdapter = new  YoutubeAdapter(arrayList, getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(youtubeAdapter);
```

Me gustaría que el objeto dataSetListYouTube, en lugar de recibir por parámetro la url harcodeada uno a uno, recogiera los datos desde una base de datos Firebase.

El **principal problema** que me encuentro es que si creo un nodo Videos/Link, el campo "nombre/...." debe ser único, por lo que a la hora de captar el campo hijo, debería de hacerlo uno a uno.

La **idea**, es poder insertar la url desde Firebase, de modo que pueda ir añadiendo videos desde esta base de datos.
Entiendo que posteriormente debo recorrerla con un bucle for.

Gracias.